# Planes in parameter form are parallel

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

We have two planes in parameter form $$p_1:\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\\6\end{pmatrix}+λ\begin{pmatrix}1\\-2\\1\end{pmatrix}+μ\begin{pmatrix}a\\-1\\2\end{pmatrix}$$$$p_2:\begin{pmatrix}1\\4\\c\end{pmatrix}+λ\begin{pmatrix}2\\1\\2\end{pmatrix}+μ\begin{pmatrix}b\\1\\5\end{pmatrix}$$ and I want to calculate the unknown variables such that the two planes are parallel.

For that do we have to find the normal vector of each plane and then the one has to be a multiple of the other?

Or can we find it also when we have the parameter form?

Comment: You can do like you said but it is shorter to find only a normal vector of one of the two planes, and to express that the two vectors directing the other plane are orthogonal to that normal vector.